# How to get axis to display correctly on grid based (heat map) chart with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to display axis for a grid based chart (heat map) to display correctly. I can get them into the right alignment (centered with each grid whether it be row or column), but they are on top of the grid where I want to have them displayed outside of the grids.

Here's what I have so far: http://jsbin.com/hihepo/8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Provide some margins around and `translate` your chart's `g` wrapper. You have margins defined, but they are never used, so you chart stretches until `svg` element borders and there's no more space around.
2. Use `.orient('left')` for y axis and `.orient('bottom')` for x axis orientation. See [docs for `orient` method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#orient).
3. Adjust the `transform` and `text-anchor` of your x axis labels (or change the translation of their `g` wrapper).

Here's a **[demo](http://jsbin.com/qavudovuci)** for x axis labels.

Comment: Thanks. Applying the margins with the right orientation on the axes worked. One question though, is there anyway to figure out how big the margins should be based on the length of the labels' text?

Comment: @spullen There is, but it's tricky and ugly. For example, you can find the longest string in your data array, insert it into your svg as a hidden element, then call `getComputedTextLength` or `getBBox` or whatever on it, calculate the length and then set the margin.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into both of those functions.